# Didn't understand relationship 'ProcessInstanceId' in field path

Tags: apex, soql, query, approval-process, relationships

How come I can compile a query on workitem to return processinstanceID but the related targetobjectid (and then of course the targetobjectid.name ) return the error:

Edit - sorry I wasn't clear but ultimately I want the targetobject's name field - to display to users.

ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId.name brings  " Didn't understand relationship 'TargetObjectId' in field path.... type error"

> Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship
>   'ProcessInstanceId' in field path. If you are attempting to use a
>   custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom
>   relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
>   the appropriate names. at line 15 column 50

```
public class UsersItemsToApprove {

public UsersItemsToApprove() {

}


public UsersItemsToApprove (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}


   public List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> getWorkItems() {
    List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> results = new List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem>();
    List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> allitems = [SELECT ElapsedTimeInDays, 
           ProcessInstanceId,  ProcessInstanceId.targetobjectid
            FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
            WHERE ActorId= :UserInfo.getUserId()];


    for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem thisitem : allitems)



    {

            results.add(thisitem);

    }
    return results;
}



}
```

Comment: Try `ProcessInstance.targetobjectid FROM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the relationship name when getting cross-object fields (a [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join)). You can get this value using:

```
system.debug(ProcessInstanceWorkItem.ProcessInstanceId.getDescribe().getRelationshipName());
```

The above yields `ProcessInstance`, so you should do:

```
SELECT ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem
```

You have to continue this process on down the line. Only the final cross-object field will end up being unmodified. So if you want to go a third level, you would use:

```
SELECT ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Name FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId.name brings back the " Didn't understand relationship 'TargetObjectId' in field path."

Comment: Works for me...did you try to add more fields after? Like `ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId.Name`? You would have to also use the relationship name for `TargetObjectId`, which would be `TargetObject`.

Comment: ah, that's it, again i was having the id in there.... feeling slow today I guess. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement what was already answered:

When querying attributes of a related (lookup) object, you should access:

- *ProcessInstance.Name* for standard lookups (your case);
- *Custom_lookup__r.Attribute__c* for custom object lookups;

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should work

```
List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> allitems = [SELECT ElapsedTimeInDays, 
           ProcessInstanceId,ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
            FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
            WHERE ActorId= :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```